Singularity/Nexflow script won't load Tensorflow from .sif on cluster
I'm trying to run a singularity/nextflow script on an HPC. This script utilizes tensorflow, which is specified in the docker image I used to pull the initial .sif file from lpryszcz/deeplexicon:latest. However, whenever I try to import tensorflow within my nextflow pipeline like this:
 python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print('TensorFlow version:', tf.__version__)" >> ${params.resultsDir}/cuda_paths.txt

I am presented with this error:
  ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  
  
  Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

I initially attempted to fix this by determining where my libcuda.so file was:
ldconfig -p | grep libcuda
Which turned out to be:
libcudart.so.10.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.10.0
And then simply adding the libucda.so.10.0 path directly to LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
However the issue still persists.
For more context, the input files for my job are as follows:
The nextflow pipeline script looks like this:
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow 
process demultiplex {
    input:
    
    path fast5, from: params.fast5

    output:

    script:
    if(params.demultiplex)
    """
    mkdir -p ${params.resultsDir}

    python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print('TensorFlow version:', tf.__version__)" >> ${params.resultsDir}/cuda_paths.txt

    python3 /deeplexicon/deeplexicon.py dmux -p ${fast5} -f multi -m models/resnet20-final.h5 > ${params.resultsDir}/output.tsv
    """
    else
    """
        echo "Skipped"
    """
}

Which always throws the error when trying to import tensorflow.
And the config file like this (with some changes made for anonymity):
 params{
    // Path to the sample description file
    fast5 = "/some_path/Deeplexicon/RNA004/fast5_pass"
    resultsDir = "/some_path/Deeplexicon/7_16_2"
    demultiplex = true
}

singularity {
    enabled = true
    autoMounts = false
    cacheDir = '/some_path/work/singularity_cache'

}

tower {
    enabled = false
    endpoint = '-'
    accessToken = 'nextflowTowerToken'
}

process{
    cpus = 1
    executor = 'slurm'
    queue = 'pascal_gpu'
    perJobMemLimit = true

    containerOptions='--bind (All of the CUDA paths from module show CUDA/10.1.243)'

    withName:demultiplex {
    container = 'deeplexicon_latest.sif'
    clusterOptions = '--gres=gpu:1'
    memory = { params.demultiplex ? 8.GB + (2.GB * (task.attempt-1)) : 2.GB }
    errorStrategy = { task.exitStatus == 130 ? 'retry' : 'terminate' }
    maxRetries = 3
}

}

Finally, my slurm job submission script looks like this:
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=deeplexicon_RNA002
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=10
#SBATCH --mem=2G
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=pascal_gpu
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1


module purge
module load legacy-software
module load CUDA/10.0.130
module load Java/11.0.20


export APPTAINER_TMPDIR=$SCRATCH_VO_USER/apptainer-tmp
export APPTAINER_CACHEDIR=$SCRATCH_USER/apptainer-cache

export NXF_SINGULARITY_CACHEDIR=/some_path/work/singularity_cache

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


/some_path/tools/nextflow/nextflow-22.10.0-all -c /some_path/Deeplexicon/nextflow_scripts/deeplexicon.conf run /some_path/Deeplexicon/nextflow_scripts/deeplexicon.nf

Really not sure why this is not recognizing tensorflow upon import.


ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
file or directory

One way might be to append --nv to your singularity.runOptions, to enable Nvidia support, for example:
singularity {
  enabled = true
  runOptions = '--nv'
}

If that fails, you might like to try binding your system's libcuda.so.1 to somewhere in the container's $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can use the singularity.runOptions (or docker.runOptions if using Docker) for this. For example:
singularity {
  enabled = true
  runOptions = '--bind /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1:/usr/local/nvidia/lib/libcuda.so.1'
}


Tested using Docker:
$ cat main.nf
process demultiplex {

  debug true

  container 'lpryszcz/deeplexicon:latest'

  script:
  """
  python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print('TensorFlow version:', tf.__version__)" 
  """
}

workflow {

  demultiplex()
}

$ cat nextflow.config 
docker {
  enabled = true
  runOptions = '-v /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1:/usr/local/nvidia/lib/libcuda.so.1'
}

Results:
$ nextflow run main.nf 

 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.04.3

Launching `main.nf` [astonishing_swirles] DSL2 - revision: 4d3ac3440f

executor >  local (1)
[4e/67997d] process > demultiplex [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
TensorFlow version: 1.13.1



Thank you for the response!
I added this:
runOptions = '--bind /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib'
Since running ldconfig -p | grep libcuda in the process gives that directory + libcudart.so.10.0.
But I now get:
FATAL:   container creation failed: mount hook function failure: mount /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib->/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib error:
while mounting /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib: mount source /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib doesn't exist

@Brendan There might be some misunderstanding. Note that --bind expects a user-bind path with the format src:dest, where 'src' is a local path on your machine and 'dest' in the path inside the container. In your case here, you're trying to bind the /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib on your machine but it (i.e. the source) doesn't exist. Also note that libcuda.so.1 is not the same as libcudart.so.10.0. Tensorflow just wants libcuda.so.1 AFAIK. What did you get when you bind your local libcuda.so.1?

Hi Steve, I was finally able to fix the issue by adding  runOptions = '--nv' and then actually removing all of the bind options. Thank you for the help regardless!

@Brendan Great! Glad you got it working. I've made a note of this in the answer above.
